# C# WPF passing UTF16 string to a function that accepts char *

Tags: c#, wpf, pinvoke

I've created a wpf project which has a helper static class that contains all my c++ backend code. One such function is defined as:

```
public static unsafe class Backend {

    [DllImport("Mandel.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public extern static void write(void* ptr, char* path);
}
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            string path = "mypath";
            InitializeComponent();
            unsafe
            {
                char *p; //convert
                void* myObj = Backend.init_obj(1920, 1080);
                Backend.gen(myObj);
                Backend.write(myObj, p);
            }
        }
    }
```

The `void* ptr` is actually my object that is casted in order to marshall it onto the C# side. The problem I face is that whenever I try to invoke this with a string literal in wpf, I get that Visual C# cannot convert this because string literals are encoded in UTF16. Naturally I tried many things other than manually copying the relevant bytes to a char array. Any tips?

Comment: Instead of trying to create the `char*` parameter yourself, change the declaration so the second parameter is `string` and let the Runtime marshal it for you. Because it's an ANSI string, you're never going to get full unicode fidelity but that's a problem created by the C++ code.

Comment: @madreflection This does not specifically answer the question, but it worked! Change it to an answer and I'll vote it.

Comment: If I were to specifically answer the question, it would probably include a call to `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` to allocate a buffer, a call to `Encoding.Default.GetBytes` to convert the string, and the `path` parameter would need to be declared as `byte*`. I'll leave you with that in case you want to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things the CLR can do pretty well for interop with C/C++ code is marshalling data structures between managed and unmanaged code.  Since strings are pretty important, a lot of work went into making strings marshal as well as possible.

As a side note, you're using `void*` for the context object that's created by `init` and passed to `write`.  Since you're just handing it back, you can replace it with `IntPtr` and avoid `unsafe` blocks altogether.  `IntPtr` is always the size of a pointer in the current architecture.

First, let's change the declaration of the imported functions.  `CharSet.Ansi` tells it to marshal strings as ANSI.  The `ptr` parameter becomes `IntPtr`

```cs
[DllImport("Mandel.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public extern static IntPtr init(int width, int height);

[DllImport("Mandel.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public extern static void gen(IntPtr ptr);

[DllImport("Mandel.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public extern static void write(IntPtr ptr, string path);
```

And from there, you can figure out how to modify the function to deallocate `ptr` and any others you have to call.

Using those functions becomes a lot easier and a lot cleaner.  You don't need the `unsafe` block and you can pass `path` directly to `write`.

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    string path = "mypath";
    InitializeComponent();

    IntPtr myObj = Backend.init_obj(1920, 1080);
    Backend.gen(myObj);
    Backend.write(myObj, path);
}
```

---

Original comment that got it working:

> Instead of trying to create the `char*` parameter yourself, change the declaration so the second parameter is `string` and let the Runtime marshal it for you. Because it's an ANSI string, you're never going to get full unicode fidelity but that's a problem created by the C++ code.

Comment: This actually helps a lot for someone that was printing hello world with C# a few hours back. Thanks!

Comment: That's pretty impressive. It's difficult to predict if the extra information will be helpful or just muddy the waters. I'm glad it was helpful.